# Room how to type convert a really complex data class?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-room

I want to use Room database to store data about my Itineraries, but the problem is that my Itinerary data class is really complex due to the large amount of data from API call. What is an optimal way of writing type converter for these types of classes?

**Main class stored in Room**

```
data class ItineraryModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val itineraryId: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "price_details")
    @TypeConverters(PriceDetailsModelConverter::class)
    val priceDetails: PriceDetailsModel? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "slice_data")
    @TypeConverters(SliceDataModelConverter::class)
    val sliceData: SliceDataModel? = null
)
```

**SliceDataModel**

```
data class SliceDataModel(
    val slice: SliceModel
)
```

**SliceModel**

```
data class SliceModel(
    val info: InfoSliceModel,
    val airline: AirlineModel,
    val arrival: ArrivalModel,
    val departure: DepartureModel,
    val flightData: FlightDataModel
)
```

**InfoSliceModel**

```
data class InfoSliceModel(
    val connectionCount: Int,
    val duration: String,
    val id: Int,
    val stopCount: Int
)
```

**AirlineModel**

```
data class AirlineModel(
    val logo: String,
    val name: String
)
```

**Arrival/Departure Models (the same)**

```
data class ArrivalModel(
    val airport: AirportModel,
    val datetime: DatetimeModel
)
```

**AirportModel**

```
data class AirportModel(
    val city: String,
    val code: String,
    val country: String,
    val name: String,
)
```

**DatetimeModel**

```
data class DatetimeModel(
    val date: String,
    val dateDisplay: String,
    val time24h: String,
)
```

**FlightDataModel**

```
data class FlightDataModel(
    val flights: List<FlightModel>
)
```

**FlightModel**

```
data class FlightModel(
    val arrival: ArrivalModel,
    val departure: DepartureModel,
    val info: InfoModel
)
```

**InfoModel**

```
data class InfoModel(
    val aircraft: String,
    val aircraftType: String,
    val cabinClass: String,
    val cabinName: String,
    val duration: String,
    val stopCount: Int
)
```

As you can see, there's a lot of data. How can I convert it optimally?

Comment: In this case, I think I will use a serialization library to convert `priceDetails` and`sliceData` to big JSON string, and deserialize it back when I need to query them.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy solution to this is to use a serialization library, which allows converting big and complex objects into a `String` JSON, so you can store them in your Room database easily. I recommend using Kotlinx.serialization library, you can follow this [link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/README.md#setup) to setup with Gradle.

After installing the library, annotate all your data class with `@Serializable`. For example:

```
@Serializable
@Entity
data class ItineraryModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val itineraryId: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "price_details")
    @TypeConverters(PriceDetailsModelConverter::class)
    val priceDetails: PriceDetailsModel? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "slice_data")
    @TypeConverters(SliceDataModelConverter::class)
    val sliceData: SliceDataModel? = null
)
```

Do the same thing with all other data classes that are involved in your model. After doing this, go to your type converters:

**PriceDetailsModelConverter:**

```
class PriceDetailsModelConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun convertToJsonString(priceDetails: PriceDetailsModel?): String {
         return Json.encodeToString(priceDetails)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun convertToObject(json: String): PriceDetailsModel? {
         return Json.decodeFromString(json)
    }

}
```

**SliceDataModelConverter:**

```
class SliceDataModelConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun convertToJsonString(sliceDetails: SliceDataModel?): String {
         return Json.encodeToString(sliceDetails)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun convertToObject(json: String): SliceDataModel? {
         return Json.decodeFromString(json)
    }

}
```

And everything is OK, when store the big model object, `priceDetails` and `sliceDetails` will be stored in the form of String JSON, when you query the database, you will receive them as model objects.

Later on, if you want to select rows based on a price condition for example, you have to use `LIKE` sql operator since the `priceDetails` is stored as String, this maybe the only drawback of this approach.

Comment: Thank you really much for your help, it all works perfectly just like you said. I edited your answer since you probably overlooked the function invoke parameter in SliceDataModelConverter (was priceDetails instead of sliceDetails). Have a good day.